# Why does subtracting php variables with values over 1000 miscalculate

Tags: php, html

I pass/carry $total in from a previous page. Then I input $amount_tendered, then pass both variables to a final PHP page to be processed. All works perfect as long as I keep my variable values under 1000. If over 1000 the two variables do not subtract properly. Very strange in fact, when I minus $total from $amount_tendered, it always equals 1. If I hard code the variables right before the subtraction process, it calculates properly. You will notice my two // items in the PHP code below. I know it has to be something I am doing wrong when passing variables from page to page. Like variable type or something, but just not sure.

Thanks

> HTML

```
<?php 
$total = isset($_REQUEST['total']) ? $_REQUEST['total'] : "";
?>
<form action="cash_final.php" method="post">
<?php 
  echo '
      <input type="hidden" name="total" value="' . $total . '" /> 
  ';
?>
<div class="main_style" style="">
    <input class="main_input_style" type="text" name="amount_tendered" /> 
</div>
<div class="main_style" style=""> 
    <button  type="submit" >Continue </button> 
</div>
</form>
```

> cash_final.php

```
<?php 
    $total = 0;
    $amount_tendered = 0;
    $total = isset($_REQUEST['total']) ? $_REQUEST['total'] : "";
    $amount_tendered = isset($_REQUEST['amount_tendered']) ? $_REQUEST['amount_tendered'] : "";
    //     $total = "1138.78";
    //     $amount_tendered = "2000.00";
    echo 'total = ' . $total;
    echo '<br>amount_tendered = ' . number_format($amount_tendered,2);
    $c = floatval($amount_tendered) - floatval($total);
    echo '<br>change_due = ' . number_format($c,2);
?>
```

Comment: Do you understand what `number_format()` does?

Comment: Why are you using number_format() on the values ___before___ the subtraction?

Comment: usually i dont, it was just something I tried to see if it would solve my problem, and it made no difference.  In most cases I only use number_format on my echo

Comment: [Seems to work perfectly well](https://3v4l.org/bkjGY). What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
floatval($amount_tendered) - floatval($total)
```

You need to convert the numbers to decimal or int or something numeric before doing arithmetic on them. number_format converts them to string. You cannot do arithmetic with strings.

Proof:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $total = "1138.78";
php > $amount_tendered = "2000.00";
php > echo floatval($amount_tendered) - floatval($total);
861.22
php > echo number_format($amount_tendered,2) - number_format($total, 2);
1
php >     $c = floatval($amount_tendered) - floatval($total);
php >     echo '<br>change_due = ' . number_format($c,2);
<br>change_due = 861.22
php >     $c = $amount_tendered - $total;
php >     echo '<br>change_due = ' . number_format($c,2);
<br>change_due = 861.22
php
```

Comment: I made that change and still the same problem

Comment: See my proof, that it works above. Actually it works even without floatval - as long as you do not use number_format. Maybe you have some caching issue - the web page may be cached in the server or browser - so you are not seeing your updates.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you are saying.  I think my problem now is my $total variable that I passed from the first page.  I think I got it from here

Answer (score 1):

Although strings do get type converted, Formatted strings don't and so they don't subtract. They must be unformatted.

Ex :

```
echo "2000.05" - "4000.67";
```

Will give you the answer -2000.62

But,

```
echo "2,000.05" - "4,000.67";
```

This won't work. Will display some weird answer.

Comment: Very useful info, and I understand what you are saying.  So I made the change floatval($amount_tendered) - floatval($total) and still no go.

Comment: @RickyT The type casting does not work as intended on formatted strings. So, floatval on a number_formatted string is no really helpful. Don't format them yet. Do, the subtraction first, then format the result.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it behaving strangely (it's not strange, once you know what's happening).  Think about values in PHP that are real ints or floats versus strings that happen to contain characters that look like ints or floats: `1.23` vs `"1.23"`.  To be helpful (yet sometimes dangerous), PHP will convert float-like strings to real floats in order to do arithmetic.

`number_format` will format a int/float for viewing by humans.  `number_format(1.234,2)` becomes `"1.23"` and can still be used in arithmetic.  However, anything greater than 1000 such as `number_format(1234.12,2)` becomes `"1,234.12"`.  The comma in the string, although understandable by humans, is not understandable by PHP: PHP will think `"1,234.12"` is a sting just like `"foobar"` and will not convert it for use in arithmetic.

That explains why.  Now, for what you should do: do all your arithmetic first and only use `number_format` just before you display the results to humans.